# Understanding Variable Type

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a variable declared as `var` that I want to implicitly declare.  I have used the code `Console.WriteLine(returnData.GetType();` which returns `ConsoleApp1.GreenGlue[]` -> which I do not follow on how to change the type of `var returnData;`

This is how the syntax is set...snippet if more code needs to be added let me know.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var returnData = JsonConert.DeserializeObject<GreenGlue[]>(reply);
}


public class GreenGlue
{
    public string BC { get; set; }
    public List<BL> BL { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you not declare it as GreenGlue[]  ?  Using var implicitly declares the type already - or do you mean explicitly

Comment: @ChrisCarr -> yes so sorry for my mishap.

Comment: The best tip is: don‘t use var, set the type explicitly. Trust me, except in a few cases, you‘re not doing yourself a favor with var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is an implicitly declared variable, meaning the compiler will infer the type from the right-hand side.

Since you are using Json.Net, you will have to change the generic parameter for `DeserializeObject` whatever result you want.

Comment: reply is a string variable - does that mean I would be fine to declare returnData as string as well?

Comment: @IcyPopTarts not necessarily. its what *you* want to make of it.

Comment: If I declare as string I get a compile error of Cannot implicitly convert type 'GreenGlue[]' to 'string'

Comment: @IcyPopTarts `DeserializeObject<T>` is declared like this: `T DeserializeObject<T>(string json)`. The angle brackets declare the result type.

Comment: See my edit on how my GreenGlue class is set-up.  Maybe that will help better clarify what is going on with my code

Comment: @IcyPopTarts it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Is the [] meaning I am returning an array, so therefore I can not set the variable returnData as a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160859/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-icypoptarts).